# Call WL.Client.invokeProcedure after custom DirectUpdate

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-adapters

I have a similar problem than [MobileFirst Direct update customization using adapter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36064575/mobilefirst-direct-update-customization-using-adapter/37572247#37572247)
But I'm not using the Adapter to modify the DirectUpdate, I'm trying to make a record about the state of the DirectUpdate when it finish, but seems that the call to the adapter not works. There is any restriction to call WL.Client.invokeProcedure on main.js after the DirectUpdate finish?

Update, my source code:

```
/**
 * Busy indicator
 */
var busyInd;
/**
 * Custom listener for MobileFirst DirectUpdate
 */
var directUpdateCustomListener = {
        /**
         * Call when DirectUpdate starts
         * @param totalSize
         */
          onStart: function(totalSize){
              console.log(JSON.stringify(totalSize));
              busyInd = new WL.BusyIndicator("ion-side-menu-content", {text: MENSAJE_DIRECT_UPDATE});
              busyInd.show();
          },
          /**
           * Call on every DirectUpdate step
           * @param status
           * @param totalSize
           * @param completedSize
           */
          onProgress: function(status,totalSize,completedSize){
            console.log('DirectUpdate-'+status+':  -------- -------- ---------- ------------- PROGRESS: '+completedSize+' of '+totalSize);
          },
          /**
           * Call when DirectUpdate finish
           * @param status Status of the finished DirectUpdate
           */
          onFinish: function(status){
              console.log(JSON.stringify(status));
              busyInd.hide();

              var options = {
                        onSuccess: success,
                        onFailure: fail
              };
              function success(data) {

                  var dataDirectUpdate = new Object();
                  dataDirectUpdate.device = data.deviceID;
                  dataDirectUpdate.version = window.device.version;     
                  dataDirectUpdate.model = window.device.model;
                  dataDirectUpdate.platform = window.device.platform;
                  dataDirectUpdate.appVersion = WL.Client.getAppProperty(WL.AppProperty.APP_VERSION);
                  dataDirectUpdate.status = status;
                  console.log(JSON.stringify(dataDirectUpdate));


                  var invocationData = {
                          adapter:"OracleAdapter",
                          procedure:"directUpdateData",
                          parameters: [dataDirectUpdate]
                  };

                  function ProcSuccess(dataSuccess) {
                      console.log('insert OK'+JSON.stringify(dataSuccess));
                      if (status == 'SUCCESS'){
                            WL.SimpleDialog.show('Title', 'Success',
                                    [{
                                        text : 'OK',
                                        handler : function() {                                      
                                            WL.Client.reloadApp();
                                        }
                                    }]
                                );
                            }
                            else {
                                WL.SimpleDialog.show(TITULO_DIRECT_UPDATE, ERROR_DIRECT_UPDATE,
                                        [{
                                            text : 'OK',
                                            handler : function() {
                                                wl_directUpdateChallengeHandler.submitFailure();
                                            }
                                        }]
                                    );
                            }                                             
                  }               
                  function ProcFail() {
                      console.log('insert fail');
                        WL.SimpleDialog.show(TITULO_DIRECT_UPDATE, ERROR_DIRECT_UPDATE,
                                [{
                                    text : 'OK',
                                    handler : function() {
                                        wl_directUpdateChallengeHandler.submitFailure();
                                    }
                                }]
                            );                      
                  }

                  WL.Client.connect({
                        onSuccess: function(){
                            WL.Client.invokeProcedure(invocationData, {
                                onSuccess: ProcSuccess,
                                onFailure: ProcFail
                            });
                        },
                        onFailure: ProcFail
                    });               



                }

                function fail() {
                    WL.SimpleDialog.show('Title', 'Error',
                            [{
                                text : 'OK',
                                handler : function() {
                                    wl_directUpdateChallengeHandler.submitFailure();
                                }
                            }]
                        );
                }   
                WL.Device.getID(options);         

          }
        };
/**
 * Handler override to control MobileFirst DirectUpdate
 * @param directUpdateData Data from the DirectUpdate
 * @param directUpdateContext Java Object with context of the DirectUpdate
 */
wl_directUpdateChallengeHandler.handleDirectUpdate = function(directUpdateData,directUpdateContext) {
            // custom WL.SimpleDialog for Direct Update
            console.log(JSON.stringify(directUpdateData));
            WL.SimpleDialog.show('Title', 'Question',
                [{
                    text : 'OK',
                    handler : function() {
                        directUpdateContext.start(directUpdateCustomListener);
                        // Additional code here.
                    }
                },
                {
                    text : 'NO',
                    handler : function() {
                        //wl_directUpdateChallengeHandler.submitFailure();
                        // Additional code here.
                    }
                }]
            );
        };
```

Comment: Please add your **code**, of how you are modifying the Direct Update flow as well as mention if the application or adapter(s) are protected in any way.

Comment: Added as update to my original post

Comment: None. Please provide a sample project that recreates your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Confirmed, it's impossible to do that in the way I'm trying to do.
Thanks Idan Adar to try help me.